# Passing $_POST data from page to page in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, post

Does anyone know how to transfer $_POST data (HTML form data) from one page to another in Drupal?

I have two PHP pages I'm including in two different Drupal nodes, but I can't pass POST data between them.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: something wrong with $_POST array ?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) as they do exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by SenorAmor, sessions are the right way to share data between HTTP requests. If you are actually building a multi-step form in Drupal, you shouldn't do it by including forms in node. You should instead [create a module](https://drupal.org/node/361112) and use [Drupal's form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7) which can be used to [build multi-step forms](http://growingventuresolutions.com/blog/drupal-7-multistep-forms-using-variable-functions).

Answer (score 0):

+1 SenorArmor's suggestion, sounds like it's what you need.

However, if you're looking for a way to *temporarily* pass data (for example, going through two related forms) and you don't want to keep it in `$_SESSION`, you might be interested in hidden `<input>` tags. Put them in any form you want to keep old "POSTED" data in, and the values will be retained and passed into the next page submit (And thus, in the `$_POST` on the final page). *Be sure to validate these inputs;* people can change them too.